# Unexpected FileTraceListener Behavior with AppDomains and Threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, logging, appdomain, trace

I have the following environment:

- Windows 7, 64-bit Ultimate EN with latest SPs
- Visual Studio 2013 with latest SPs
- .NET Framework 3.5 with latest SPs
- my Console application

### Goal

Two AppDomains each with its own thread write Trace.WriteLine() messages to two local file Trace listeners

### Implementation

1. My console application has two system.diagnostics trace listerns "ListenerA" and "ListenerB" defined in the App.config file. These listeners log to local text files called A.log and B.log
2. My console application creates an AppDomain for each trace listener.
3. Each AppDomain creates one thread.
4. The thread worker function logs 5 messages using Trace.WriteLine() that look like: "ListenerA, 16:48:49, 6" (AppDomain.FriendlyName, Time, ManagedThreadID)
5. The file trace listener inherits the abstract System.Diagnostics.TraceListener class.

### Resources:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
      <listeners>
        <remove name="Default"/>
        <add name="ListenerA" type="TraceListeners.Listener, TraceListenersConsole" initializeData="A.log"/>
        <add name="ListenerB" type="TraceListeners.Listener, TraceListenersConsole" initializeData="B.log"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

**TraceListener**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace TraceListeners
{
    public class Listener : TraceListener
    {
        private FileStream theFileStream;

        private string _initializeData;

        public Listener(string initializeData)
        {
            this._initializeData = initializeData;

            this.theFileStream = GetStreamWriter(Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\TraceLog", initializeData));
        }


        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            this.WriteToFile(message);
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            this.theFileStream.Flush();
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            this.Write(message + "\r\n");
        }

        public override bool IsThreadSafe
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void WriteToFile(string message)
        {
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
            this.theFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        private FileStream GetStreamWriter(string path)
        {
            return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        }
    }
}
```

**static void Main**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TraceListenersConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static AppDomain _domainA;
        private static AppDomain _domainB;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomainSetup domainSetupA = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
            };

            AppDomainSetup domainSetupB = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
            };

            _domainA = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ListenerA", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, domainSetupA);
            _domainA.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(AppDomainCallback));

            _domainB = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ListenerB", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, domainSetupB);
            _domainB.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(AppDomainCallback));

            //AppDomainCallback();
            //AppDomainCallback();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static private void AppDomainCallback()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadWorker);
        }

        static private void ThreadWorker(object obj)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                int threadID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), threadID));
                Trace.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(threadID);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**
The log files A.log and B.log each should contain ten log entries like below:

```
ListenerA, 16:48:49, 6
ListenerA, 16:48:50, 6
ListenerA, 16:48:51, 6
ListenerA, 16:48:52, 6
ListenerA, 16:48:53, 6
ListenerB, 16:48:49, 7
ListenerB, 16:48:50, 7
ListenerB, 16:48:51, 7
ListenerB, 16:48:52, 7
ListenerB, 16:48:53, 7
```

**Actual behavior:**

A.log contains:

```
ListenerB, 17:06:40, 12
ListenerB, 17:06:41, 12
ListenerA, 17:06:42, 11
ListenerB, 17:06:43, 12
ListenerB, 17:06:44, 12
```

B.log contains:

```
ListenerB, 17:06:40, 12
ListenerB, 17:06:41, 12
ListenerA, 17:06:42, 11
ListenerB, 17:06:43, 12
ListenerB, 17:06:44, 12
```

**Notes:**

- If I omit the AppDomain creation and call the AppDomainCallback
  function directly then everything works as expected.
- I am analysing a production problem where the AppDomain, thread and TraceLitener are used in this way.

Why do the log files contain only 5 entries? why not as expected 10 entries?